# Select text in contenteditable after it has changed

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, onfocus, cursor-position

I am about to write a input system for a web application that is a bit more complex. We have Labels in our text that are weather displayed as a bootstrap label (when the contenteditable div is blured) or displayed as handlebars e.g. `{{firstname}}` when the text is focused.

The changing in states is done by `jQueries $().html(content)` where I change the content based on the source when I focus the text field.

**The problem is**: if I click the text, I don't want to need to click a second time to place the cursor, because the text changed. It works as long I don't click inside of a tag but inside the contenteditable root element. but if I click inside of a tag inside the contenteditable, the cursor is not set.

my idea was to get the mouse position when clicking the contenteditable and then set the text cursor to exact that position when I have changed the text. But while I know, how I set the cursor to a specific offset inside a text node, I have no clue how to get this necessary offset when clicking. any ideas?

Edit: Here is the behaviour in a little screencast: https://youtu.be/RZvHxxM6wsQ

Edit2: Here is the problem reproduced on the smallest kind of working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8z5Lnxef/3/

Comment: can you put some kind of simple demo, maybe, it's hard to recreate  your situation

Comment: @Z.better I added a fiddle

Comment: sorry for late reply, I see your problem,, but sorry again I have no idea how to solve it,,,,looks tricky